# JavaScript callback after an element is added to a document

Tags: ajax

I want to be able to do some client-side calls after the page is fully loaded. However, since some of the contents get loaded through Ajax, I can't use the document's onload callback. Is there anyway to attack a callback to an element that gets added to the HTML document using Ajax; something like this:

```
<input id="myinput" type="submit" onload="myhandler" />
```

So I want the `myhandler()` function to be called after the input element is added to the document after an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event in JQuery called `AjaxComplete`. I do not know if you can use in this case.

Comment: The problem is that I am using AjaxControlToolkit (ASP.NET), so it does the handling itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to call `myhandler()` in Ajax callback function after appending elements to DOM. Let's say

```
function drawInputFieldDependsOnAjaxResponse(response){

var whateverDiv = document.gelementById('whateverDiv');
   /**
   do some stuff with response
   */

    // append input field
    whateverDiv.appendChild(InputField);

    //call handler function for input field
    myhandler();
}
```